# Change background of Android Wear Watch Face every two minutes

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I need to change the background of my Android Wear watch face every two minutes. How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
public class SomethingWatchFaceService extends CanvasWatchFaceService {
private static final String TAG = "SomethingWatchFaceService";



@Override
public Engine onCreateEngine() {
    /* provide your watch face implementation */
    return new Engine();
}



/* implement service callback methods */
private class Engine extends CanvasWatchFaceService.Engine {

    Bitmap mBackgroundBitmap;
    Bitmap mBackgroundScaledBitmap;

    String[] backgroundColor = {"red", "green", "blue"};

    int let= new Random().nextInt(backgroundColor.length);
    String randomColor = (backgroundColor[let]);

    Integer[] listDrawable = {R.drawable.back1, R.drawable.back2};

    //Generating the list number for drawable
    Random randNumForDrawable = new Random();
    int  n = randNumForDrawable.nextInt(2);


    //Member variables
    private Typeface WATCH_TEXT_TYPEFACE = Typeface.create( Typeface.SERIF, Typeface.NORMAL );

    private static final int MSG_UPDATE_TIME_ID = 42;
    private long mUpdateRateMs = 1000;

    private Time mDisplayTime;

    private Paint mBackgroundColorPaint;
    private Paint mTextColorPaint;

    private boolean mHasTimeZoneReceiverBeenRegistered = false;
    private boolean mIsInMuteMode;
    private boolean mIsLowBitAmbient;

    private float mXOffset;
    private float mYOffset;

    private int mBackgroundColor = Color.parseColor(randomColor);
    private int mTextColor = Color.parseColor( "white" );

    final BroadcastReceiver mTimeZoneBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            mDisplayTime.clear( intent.getStringExtra( "time-zone" ) );
            mDisplayTime.setToNow();
        }
    };

    private final Handler mTimeHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch( msg.what ) {
                case MSG_UPDATE_TIME_ID: {
                    invalidate();
                    if( isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode() ) {
                        long currentTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        long delay = mUpdateRateMs - ( currentTimeMillis % mUpdateRateMs );
                        mTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed( MSG_UPDATE_TIME_ID, delay );
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };











    @Override
    public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        super.onCreate(holder);
         /* load the background image */
        Resources resources = SomethingWatchFaceService.this.getResources();
        Drawable backgroundDrawable = resources.getDrawable(listDrawable[n]);
        mBackgroundBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) backgroundDrawable).getBitmap();

        setWatchFaceStyle( new WatchFaceStyle.Builder( SomethingQuotesWatchFaceService.this )
                        .setBackgroundVisibility( WatchFaceStyle.BACKGROUND_VISIBILITY_INTERRUPTIVE )
                        .setCardPeekMode( WatchFaceStyle.PEEK_MODE_SHORT)
                        .setShowSystemUiTime( false )
                        .build()
        );

        initBackground();
        initDisplayText();

        mDisplayTime = new Time();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties) {
        super.onPropertiesChanged(properties);
        /* get device features (burn-in, low-bit ambient) */
        if( properties.getBoolean( PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION, false ) ) {
            mIsLowBitAmbient = properties.getBoolean( PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT, false );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimeTick() {
        super.onTimeTick();
        /* the time changed */
        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAmbientModeChanged(boolean inAmbientMode) {
        super.onAmbientModeChanged(inAmbientMode);
        // when Ambient Mode changes, we changes the color of the background paint.
        if( inAmbientMode ) {
            mTextColorPaint.setColor( Color.parseColor( "grey" ) );
            mBackgroundColorPaint.setColor( Color.parseColor( "black" ) );
        } else {
            mTextColorPaint.setColor( Color.parseColor( "white" ) );
            mBackgroundColorPaint.setColor( Color.parseColor( randomColor ) );
        }

        if( mIsLowBitAmbient ) {
            mTextColorPaint.setAntiAlias( !inAmbientMode );
        }

        invalidate();
        updateTimer();

    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas, Rect bounds) {

        drawBackground( canvas, bounds );

        int width = bounds.width();
        int height = bounds.height();

        // Draw the background, scaled to fit.

        if (mBackgroundScaledBitmap == null
                || mBackgroundScaledBitmap.getWidth() != width
                || mBackgroundScaledBitmap.getHeight() != height) {
            mBackgroundScaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBackgroundBitmap,
                    width, height, true /* filter */);
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBackgroundScaledBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        mDisplayTime.setToNow();


        drawTimeText( canvas );






    }
    private void initBackground() {
        mBackgroundColorPaint = new Paint();
        mBackgroundColorPaint.setColor( mBackgroundColor );
    }
    private void drawBackground( Canvas canvas, Rect bounds ) {
        canvas.drawRect( 0, 0, bounds.width(), bounds.height(), mBackgroundColorPaint );
    }



    private void initDisplayText() {
        mTextColorPaint = new Paint();
        mTextColorPaint.setColor( mTextColor );
        mTextColorPaint.setTypeface( WATCH_TEXT_TYPEFACE );
        mTextColorPaint.setAntiAlias( true );
        mTextColorPaint.setTextSize( getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.text_size ) );
    }

    private void updateTimer() {
        mTimeHandler.removeMessages( MSG_UPDATE_TIME_ID );
        if( isVisible() && !isInAmbientMode() ) {
            mTimeHandler.sendEmptyMessage( MSG_UPDATE_TIME_ID );
        }
    }



    private void drawTimeText( Canvas canvas ) {
        String timeText = getHourString() + ":" + String.format( "%02d", mDisplayTime.minute );
        if( isInAmbientMode() || mIsInMuteMode ) {
            timeText += ( mDisplayTime.hour < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";
        } else {
            timeText += String.format( ":%02d", mDisplayTime.second);
        }
        canvas.drawText( timeText, mXOffset, mYOffset, mTextColorPaint );
    }

    private String getHourString() {
        if( mDisplayTime.hour % 12 == 0 )
            return "12";
        else if( mDisplayTime.hour <= 12 )
            return String.valueOf( mDisplayTime.hour );
        else
            return String.valueOf( mDisplayTime.hour - 12 );
    }




    @Override
    public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
        super.onVisibilityChanged(visible);
        /* the watch face became visible or invisible */
        if( visible ) {
            if( !mHasTimeZoneReceiverBeenRegistered ) {

                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter( Intent.ACTION_TIMEZONE_CHANGED );
                InspirationalQuotesWatchFaceService.this.registerReceiver( mTimeZoneBroadcastReceiver, filter );

                mHasTimeZoneReceiverBeenRegistered = true;
            }

            mDisplayTime.clear( TimeZone.getDefault().getID() );
            mDisplayTime.setToNow();
        } else {
            if( mHasTimeZoneReceiverBeenRegistered ) {
                SomethingQuotesWatchFaceService.this.unregisterReceiver( mTimeZoneBroadcastReceiver );
                mHasTimeZoneReceiverBeenRegistered = false;
            }
        }

        updateTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplyWindowInsets(WindowInsets insets) {
        super.onApplyWindowInsets(insets);

        mYOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.y_offset );

        if( insets.isRound() ) {
            mXOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.x_offset_round );
        } else {
            mXOffset = getResources().getDimension( R.dimen.x_offset_square );
        }
    }
}
```

}

> (Disregard the random functions in there, I'm choosing a random background image and a random background color)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or you don't know where/how to start? Please provide us with some more information.

Comment: @EdwinLambregts I've added my code

Answer (score 2):

You will receive regular [`WatchFaceService.Engine.onTimeTick`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine.html#onTimeTick()) callbacks. In the callback check when was the last time you changed the background. If the change was longer than 2 minutes, change the background and redraw.

The choice of the background should be a part of your model. Your drawing method should merely look at the model and draw whatever is in the model. As the model changes, the draw method will do the right thing.

Comment: How do I check when the last time the background changed? And also, how do I redraw it?

Comment: You keep around a field where you write when was the last time you drew the background. When the difference is larger than two minutes, you redraw. For drawing a watch face, please consult the training or samples.

Comment: I've added my code, could you please take a look? Thanks for everything.

Comment: You have this field: mBackgroundScaledBitmap. Make it an array of size two and load both bitmaps into that array in onCreate. In addition use an index for this array, that says which bitmap to use (so it's always either 0 or 1). In onDraw, check when was the last switch of the index. If it was more than two minutes, switch index (0 -> 1 or 1->0). Then draw the bitmap that the index is pointing to.

Comment: This is beyond asking a question on stack overflow. Please go through the official android training: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/index.html It has several steps and it will teach you everything you need to know about how to make watch faces.

Comment: I now see what you were talking about, how do I change the index every two minutes (as you can see in my code I'm already randomly choosing and index value and hence, finding a random bitmap). I'm just confused how I should repeat the random process every two minutes.

Comment: You will get automatic callback every minute onTimeTick. Save the time stamp every time you change the background and you use this time stamp to determine if two minutes have passed.

Comment: Alright, thank you. One more thing, is the watch face updating itself every minute at the moment.

Comment: You are getting a onTimeTick callback once a minute automatically